# I am having troubling indexing a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I have a csv, and I am trying to load it into a dataframe via

```
df = pd.read_csv("watchlist.csv", sep='\s{2,}',)
```

It seems to work fine when I `print(df)`

Also, when I print columns, this is the output I get.

```
print(df.columns) #- OUTPUT:

Index([',Name,Growth,Recommendation,CurrentRatio,TotalCash,Debt,Revenue,PercentageSharesOut,PercentageInstitutions,PercentageInsiders,PricetoBook,ShortRatio,RegularMarketPrice'], dtype='object')
```

The trouble I'm having, is that when I try to then go and access a column with something like

```
med_debt = math.floor(df.Debt), or even 
print(df.Debt)
```

I get an attribute error:

```
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Debt'
```

Any assistance here would be appreicated

Comment: Your DataFrame does not have a column named `Debt`. Nor does it have columns with names like `Name`, `Growth`, etc. It has *one* column, whose name is `,Name,Growth,Recommendation,CurrentRatio,TotalCash,Debt,Revenue,PercentageSharesOut,PercentageInstitutions,PercentageInsiders,PricetoBook,ShortRatio,RegularMarketPrice`. This happens because `\s{2,}` is the wrong value to use for `sep` when reading your CSV file. I'm going to guess you meant `\s{2},`.

Comment: what does the output look like if your just do `print(df)` judging on the output of your columns it looks like there's only one column that is just a string of the column names combined.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think I added that in to try to solve a different problem, I'll remove it, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sep='\s{2,}'` parameter will cause `column` **list** to become an `object` of *type* **string**, example:

```
>>> df = pd.read_csv("weather", sep='\s{2,}')
>>> df.columns
Index(['Date/Time,Temp (C),Dew Point Temp (C),Rel Hum (%),Wind Spd (km/h),
Visibility (km),Stn Press (kPa),Weather'], dtype='object')
>>> df.index
RangeIndex(start=0, stop=8784, step=1)
```

When you try to access a specific column  `math.floor(df.Debt)` it returns

`AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Debt'`

or maybe `df["Debt"]`

```
raise KeyError(key) from err
(KeyError: 'Debt')
```

To have access on specific columns of `df` by this way, use:

```
df = pd.read_csv("watchlist.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

The separator is not separating the csv correctly, try leaving it out and letting the csv reader use the default value of `,` instead.